# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'int' and 'JavaObject' when running scripts in Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, pyspark, bigdata, google-colaboratory

I am running some scripts in Google Colab and experiencing an error when trying to run the scripts for the second time. During the first execution, the code runs successfully, but when I try to run it again, I receive the following error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'int' and 'JavaObject'
```

I have tried restarting the Colab console, but this did not resolve the issue. The script takes around 15 hours to resolve this issue. And even after that for the second time the same issue is coming.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-bceb53f9f83f> in <cell line: 68>()
     66 sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate()
     67 # create RDD for files
---> 68 rdd1_filenames = sc.parallelize(filenames)
     69 
     70 # iii) Sample the the RDD to a smaller number at an appropriate position in the code. Specify a sampling factor of 0.02 for short tests. (1%)

~/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py in parallelize(self, c, numSlices)
    563         if "__len__" not in dir(c):
    564             c = list(c)    # Make it a list so we can compute its length
--> 565         batchSize = max(1, min(len(c) // numSlices, self._batchSize or 1024))
    566         serializer = BatchedSerializer(self._unbatched_serializer, batchSize)
    567 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'int' and 'JavaObject'
```

How to resolve this weird issue? Note that this issue is coming when running the below code snippet for the **second** time.

Code snippet :

```
import os, sys, math
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats
import time
import datetime
import string
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import Row


def decode_jpeg_and_label(filepath):
   // Code
   return image, label2


def resize_and_crop_image(image, label):
   // Code
   return image, label


def recompress_image(image, label):
   image = tf.cast(image, tf.uint8)
   image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(image, optimize_size=True, chroma_downsampling=False)
   return image, label


filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob(GCS_PATTERN)
sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate()
rdd1_filenames = sc.parallelize(filenames)
```

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're given code doesn't contains the one mentionned in error log. Also, it seems to be a typo as you forget to get a valid into an object

Comment: The error is coming from `rdd1_filenames = sc.parallelize(filenames)`. In the error please look at line 68.

Comment: Oh yes. Following [the documentation](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-parallelize-create-rdd/), it should be a list of int, and not a list of file names. [Example](https://medium.com/@nutanbhogendrasharma/how-to-parallelize-and-distribute-collection-in-pyspark-5f58c86d7582)